# In Terraform is it possible to move to state from one workspace to another

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

When starting of I was using the default workspace. Due to increased complexity I would like to use multiple workspaces. I want to move what is in default workspace into its own workspace or rename the default workspace as another workspace. How can I do this?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Yes it is possible to migrate state between workspaces.

I'm *assuming* that you are using S3 remote [backend](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/index.html) and terraform version >= 0.13
Let's see how this state surgery looks like:

Sample resource config that needs to be migrated between workspaces:

```
provider "local" {
  version = "2.1.0"
}

resource "local_file" "foo" {
  content  = "foo!"
  filename = "foo.bar"
}

terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = ""
    region         = ""
    kms_key_id     = ""
    encrypt        = ""
    key            = ""
    dynamodb_table = ""
  }
}
```

Let's initialise the backend for the `default` workspace and `apply`:

```
terraform init
<Initialize the backend>

terraform workspace list
* default

terraform apply
local_file.foo: Refreshing state... [id=<>]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed
```

So, as you can see a local file was already created and the state is stored in the default workspace. Terraform apply didn't change anything.

Now, we want to migrate to a new workspace:

Pull the state while you are still in the default workspace

```
terraform state pull > default.tfstate
```

Create a new workspace; let's call it `test`

```
terraform workspace new test
Created and switched to workspace "test"!
```

If you try to run `terraform state list`, you should not see any state.
Let's push the state to newly created workspace and see what's in the state; also what happens when we `apply`.

```
terraform state push default.tfstate

terraform state list
local_file.foo

terraform apply
local_file.foo: Refreshing state... [id=<>]

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Your `local_file.foo` has been migrated to the `test` workspace.

Don't forget to switch back to the `default` workspace and remove state references for this file.

```
terraform workspace select default
terraform state rm local_file.foo
Removed local_file.foo
Successfully removed 1 resource instance(s).
```

PS: I would highly recommend reading more about [managing Terraform state](https://blog.gruntwork.io/how-to-manage-terraform-state-28f5697e68fa).

Comment: Those of you who have huge states, can use this command to clean up the cruft in `default`:
```terraform state list | xargs -n 1 terraform state rm```

Answer (score 6):

None of previews answers worked for me, every time the new workspace is empty as it should be. In order to populate it you need to use `-state` as per documentation.
https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/workspace/new

So what worked:

- Create a local backup
  `terraform state pull > default.tfstate`
- Switch to local by commenting the backend block then `terraform init -migrate-state`
- Create your new workspace with `terraform workspace new -state=default.tfstate newspace` This will copy the `default` into `newspace`
- Do a `terraform plan` to check
- Uncomment backend block to switch back in the cloud then run `terraform init -migrate-state` to migrate your new workspace in the cloud
- Do a `terraform plan` and `terraform workspace list` to check.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a step by step way to do this that's a little different than the default answer.

First, we have a default s3 backend.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = "cool-bucket-name"
    key            = "production/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "cool-dynamo-db-lock-name"
  }
}
```

Now, check our workspaces.

```
terraform workspace list

  default  
* weird-workspace-name
```

Pull the state down by first commenting out the terraform backend.

```
#terraform {
#  backend "s3" {
#    encrypt        = true
#    bucket         = "cool-bucket-name"
#    key            = "production/terraform.tfstate"
#    region         = "us-east-1"
#    dynamodb_table = "cool-dynamo-db-lock-name"
#  }
#}
```

Run the command to migrate the state locally.

```
terraform init -migrate-state
```

You can check the state and see if it's still good to go.

```
terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Next, pull the state. The name of the state file is determined by what you originally gave as the key.

```
terraform workspace new cool-workspace-name

terraform state push terraform.tfstate

terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

Alright, now go clean up your old state.

```
terraform workspace select weird-workspace-name

terraform state list | cut -f 1 -d '[' | xargs -L 0 terraform state rm

terraform workspace select cool-workspace-name

terraform workspace delete weird-workspace-name
```

Run the terraform apply command again.

```
terraform apply

Apply complete! Resources: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 destroyed.
```

And now move your state back into S3, uncomment the terraform backend.tf file.

```
terraform {
  backend "s3" {
    encrypt        = true
    bucket         = "cool-bucket-name"
    key            = "production/terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    dynamodb_table = "cool-dynamo-db-lock-name"
  }
}
```

Run:

```
terraform init -migrate-state
```

I really appreciate the answer by bhalothia, I just wanted to add another step by step that's a little bit of a different case.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the backend, Terraform might be able to do the migration on its own.

For this, just update your backend configuration in the `terraform` block and then run following command to migrate the state automatically:

```
terraform init -migrate-state
```

Doing so will copy the state of all workspaces defined from old to new.

I can confirm this to be working on Terraform Cloud, even with multiple workspaces defined using a prefix.

Comment: question is about to move state from "native" workspace to another. Not about migrating state from a backend to another.